# How to make only an event public

Tags: c#, oop, events

I have an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) object in my class:

```
public class MyClass {
    ObservableCollection<Stuff> oc;
    ....
}
```

I want to be able to access [`ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) event outside the class. I can enable the `get;` method but I don't want to expose all the other method, properties and stuff.

If I wanted only a method to be available, I would make a method in `MyClass` which would then call the method on `oc` within the class. I don't know how to do this with a Event object.

So how can I make only the event public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `CollectionChanged` event with an event on `MyClass`. Perhaps like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ObservableCollection<Stuff> oc;

    //Assumes oc is never null.
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add { oc.CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { oc.CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event on MyClass, like so:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
//Assume field is assigned at this point to something non-null
myInstance.CollectionChanged += delegate {/*Do something interesting */};
```